# Saving coordinates from form

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm stuck trying to save coordinates from a form using node/express/backbone/mongoose - this may have to do with MongoDB itself

This is my schema:

```
var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 loc: {type:{type: String}, coordinates:[]}   
});
```

then

```
var My = mongoose.model('My', MySchema);

var registerMy = function(loctype, longi, lati) {
var MyMy = new My({
  loc: {
    type:loctype,
    coordinates:[longi,lati]
        }
    });
 }
```

From the HTML form

```
<form>
<fieldset>
  <label>
   Loctype:
  <input type="text" name="loctype" />
  </label>
 <label>
Longitude:
<input type="number" name="longi" />
</label>
<label>
 Latitude:
<input type="number" name="lati" />
</label>
</fieldset>
<p>
 <input type="submit" value="Register Now"/>
</p>
</form>
```

Then I get this error:

> { [MongoError: Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed
>   geometry?:{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ "37.677163", "-1.696215" ]
>   }]   name: 'MongoError',   err: 'Can\'t extract geo keys from object,
>   malformed geometry?:{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ "37.677163",
>   "-1.696215" ] }',   code: 16572,   n: 0,   connectionId: 200,   ok: 1
>   }

Comment: Ok, just solved ( I really spent more than a day before posting to here, but then it lighted up)  So the answer is just adding Number within coordinates (coordinates:[Number]} and works beautifully

Answer (score 2):

I had met with same problem, you might be trying to save location data as **String Array**, make sure that coordinates (longitude and latitude) is a **Number array**.

ie, the coordinates must be

```
[ 37.677163, -1.696215 ]
```

instead of

```
 [ "37.677163", "-1.696215" ]
```